# Something preventing iMac from sleeping

Tags: macos, sleep, power-management

Already read a lot of topics there, but none was helpful.

My energy savers are default, nothing was overriden.

`pmset -g assertions`

Shows exactly the same results, when i have / don't have issues with prevented sleep.

Only reboot helps me. Happens not everyday, from time to time.

I have installed following apps:

- Tunneblick
- Karabiner-elements
- 1password
- Little snitch firewall

Tried to turn everything off one by one, still couldn't find the issue.

Comment: Could you please [edit] and describe what you tried already instead of the *read a lot of topics there, but none was helpful*? This avoids having users suggesting or point to other questions that you already found not useful.

Answer (score 0):

Reset your SMC:
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295

If that doesn't work, try resetting the PRAM / NVRAM:
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063